# How can I use the C++ string header in Raylib?

Tags: c++, string, header, mingw

I'm trying to figure out how to declare strings in raylib (http://www.raylib.com/) source files like this:

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    /*****************/
    /*   VARIABLES   */
    /*****************/
    int screenWidth = 1600;
    int screenHeight = 900;
    string gameTitle = "Game Title";


}
```

I basically just want to be able to save strings as variables, but when I try to compile something like this it says string is not declared in this scope.

I'm trying to understand if there's some limitation to trying to use headers like the c++ string header in Raylib, or why this does not work, as I know ultimately there will be many other headers I will want to access things from.

Thank You

Comment: You need std::string. And this has nothing to do with C.

Comment: If I add std::string before the declaration the compiler throws back an error that says string is not a member of std

Comment: Also raylib examples show some files ending in .c and compiling as c99 and some files ending in .cpp which is why i included c as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Raylib is written in C99. C does not have strings, even in a string library. It only has chararrays. So using strings in raylib source files is impossible.

```
char gameTitle[] = "Game Title!";
```

You could use C++ strings in your game files, but you'd still need to compile the raylib library separately.